# array_map issue on production server

Tags: php, codeigniter, version, array-map

model.php

```
function _test() {
    return $this->db->query("SELECT 'Hello world!' AS ColumnName")->result();
}
```

controller.php

```
function test() {
    $response = $this->model->_test();
    var_dump(array_map(function($row) { return $row->ColumnName; }, $response));
}
```

I'm trying to get something like this to work on our production server, which is running PHP 5.2.9, and I realized `array_map` function is not working (it outputs nothing).

My development enviroment in running PHP 5.4.4, and this code works just fine, but I can't update our production server's PHP version, and I was hoping you guys could give me ideas on how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass an anonymous function/lambda into array map in version of PHP less than 5.3, and you have 5.2.

You can use [create_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) in 5.2, but it's ugly.

Comment: Anthony is right, I also faced same issue on my production with array_map.My production php version was 5.2.17 and my development server php version was 5.3.3